# How to put data from a database into javascript array from asp.net/vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to make a simple program to put data from a database into a javascript array and then display one result in a textbox.  Here is what I have so far

```
        Dim cmd As New IfxCommand("select first 20 fname from table", conn)
    Dim reader As IfxDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While reader.Read()
        ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Names", "'" & reader("fname") & "'")
        i += 1


    End While
    Dim cs As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    cs.Append("<script type=""text/javascript\""> function DoIt() {")
    cs.Append("var TheTextBox = document.getElementById(""TextBox1"");")
    cs.Append("TheTextBox.value = Names[0];")
    cs.Append("script>")
    TextBox1.Text = cs.ToString
```

Here is the asp

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick = "DoIt"/>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what else I am supposed to do with this.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use ASP.NET to display the values in a TextBox?

Comment: eventually I want to iterate through an array but if I did it through asp it would refresh the page everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to display the first name of your selected 20 in the `TextBox` initially and maybe lazy-load the other from client side via javascript?

Try this:

```
Using cmd = New IfxCommand("select first 20 fname from table", conn)
    Dim tbl = New DataTable
    Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        tbl.Load(reader)
        If tbl.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            Dim allNames = From row In tbl
                           Select row.Field(Of String)("fname")
            TextBox1.Text = allNames.First
            ' embed names with quotes and separate the strings by comma '
            Dim embeddedNames = From name In allNames Select String.Format("'{0}'", name)
            ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Names", String.Join(",", embeddedNames))
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Now you only need to implement the javascript function that switches the names if necessary. You can use [String `split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) then:

```
var allNames = documentGetElementById("Names").value.split(",");
```

Comment: i'm getting an error on the clientscript line saying that it can't be converted to 1 dimensional array of string

Comment: @user867621: So all works on serverside and you also have already implemented the clientside functionality to iterate the names? Can i see it? Have you debugged javascript (or at least took a look at the source) to see what happens?

Comment: i meant it won't let me compile because this line ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Names", String.Join(",", allNames))
It has the squigglies under allNames saying what the first comment said

Comment: @user867621: Oh yes, i haven't embedded the names with single quotes(`'John','James','Jim'`) which is necessary for javascript string-arrays. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: it still won't compile.... Error 1 Value of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of String)' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'.

Comment: @user867621: The previous error was on runtime not on compile time. I assume that you don't use my code or you're using a different .NET framework version. Which are you using since i'm using [this overload of `String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421) which takes an `IEnumerable(Of String)` and was new in **4.0**. If you're using **3.5** you can make it work by using the [String() overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0): `String.Join(",", embeddedNames.ToArray)`.